# ManyToMany Eloquent Laravel query issue with whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I have a ManyToMany relationship between two models: `Album` and `Media`.

Here you can see `Album` model:

```
class Album extends Model
{
    public function medias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Api\Medias\Models\Media');
    }
}
```

And here `Media` model:

```
class Media extends Model
{
    public function albums()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Api\Medias\Models\Album');
    }
}
```

Now I want to select all medias that belongs to albums with `public=1`. The eloquent query is this:

```
return $this->getModel()::whereHas('albums', function($query) {
                $query->where('public', '=', '1');
            })->get();
```

But I get this error in `whereHas` line:

`local.ERROR: ErrorException: compact(): Undefined variable: operator in...`

I am using ***Laravel Framework 5.4.36***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is like a 5.4 issue.  (https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26936)
You should try to upgrade from 5.4 to 5.5